# Gmaps API - Many markers with icon & label load slow on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) to display many markers (thousands). Loading these markers works fine if I don't add a custom label and icon to the marker (few seconds), however when I add a custom label and icon to the markers they load very slow on a **mobile phone** (about 25 seconds on Android). I created a codepen to illustrate the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXqpjN In this codepen 5000 markers are generated randomly. When you open this codepen it loads fast on a computer but slow on a mobile phone. I use the following code to create each marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    label: {
        color: '#000000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        text: 'text',
    },
    icon: {
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(24, 14),
        url: 'http://reistip.nl/assets/img/gmap/icon/emoticons/icongreenbigprice.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(50, 60),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 40),
    },

});
```

If I replace the code above with the code below (markers without a custom label and icon) it loads fine:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
```

How can I load markers that have a custom label and icon fast on a mobile phone?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: clustering and distance.

- Clustering: cluster data together with some algorithm, when the user zoom in and zoom out you show only a single point of a cluster or all.
- Distance: use a spatial algorithm (like a KD-tree) in order to quickly select only the markers near the current center of the map.

On mobile you can ussally display 100/200 markers, no more.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am actually already using a cluster library (markerclustererplus) to cluster the markers. Displaying 5000~ markers actually goes alright on a mobile phone as long as I don't add a custom label / icon to the marker. Do you, or perhaps anyone else have any idea why adding a label / icon to the markers has such a significant impact on the loading speed of the markers on a mobile phone?

Comment: You should post your code. Usually it can happen if you use the UI thread to perform heavy processing like loading bitmap and so on.

Comment: Yes, I have created a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXqpjN which illustrates the problem, got any tips for optimizing the code to improve the loading time for the markers on a mobile phone?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest three way :

**1. use clustering**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

**2. use Fusion Tables**

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1244603?hl=en

**3. use a geo server :** http://geoserver.org/

step 1: install geoserver

step 2: create a layer with your data and publish as WMS

step3: load the layer (WMS) on google map